# Wildfly do not load dll within jar after deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, dllimport, wildfly-9

I'm using wildfly version 9.

I have a jar within which in the resources folder i have an executable and multiples DLLs as dependencies.

After jar being deployed i can see that only the executable is present in deployed folder. Why my DLLs are not loaded too ?

Any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using the archive as an exploded ear in /deployments. Since then the dll in in /resources was accesibles and loaded.